# Display image with requestFileSystem and toUrl() function

Tags: html, storage, local-storage, data-storage

I made an application who use requestFileSystem. Everything works fine.
Add a new image and store it in an persistent local file system.

Does anybody know how to display an image with toUrl() ?

```
...
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, function(fs){
    fs.root.getDirectory(itemId, {create: false}, function(dirEntry) {
        var dirReader = dirEntry.createReader();
        var entries = [];
        var readEntries = function() {
           dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
            if (!results.length) {
              listResults(entries.sort(), itemId);
            } else {
              entries = entries.concat(fsdatas.dir.toArray(results));
              readEntries();
            }
          }, errorHandler);
        };
        readEntries();
    });
}, errorHandler);
...
```

And

```
function listResults(entries, itemId) {
    document.querySelector('#listRecordFiles-'+itemId).innerHTML = '';
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var i = 0;
    entries.forEach(function(entry, i) {
        i++;
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = entry.toURL();
        fragment.appendChild(img);
    });
    document.querySelector('#listRecordFiles-'+itemId).appendChild(fragment);
}
```

The output is :

```
<img src="filesystem:http://domain.tld/persistent/1/image-test.jpg">
```

But nothing is displayed on browser.

Comment: I've found the solution, this is because I used "PERSISTENT" instead of "TEMPORARY" but I don't want to use "TEMPORARY". Is anybody know how to do this with "PERSISTENT" ?

Comment: To use `PERSISTENT` storage you need to request quota. There's a quota management API for that. See https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/msg/5261d24266ba4366?pli=1

Comment: Upvote for coming back to follow up.  :)  I hadn't known toURL() until this question; that's going to make my current project easier.

Answer (score 0):

The example below is a snippet of code responsible for reading the images saved in the application's root directory, and show in the document body.

Remember, in this case, I used navigator.camera.DestinationType.**DATA_URL** to open the **PHOTOLIBRARY**, and saved the image content using **atob** (ascii to binary), so carry the image with **btoa** (binary to ascii)

```javascript
function myLoadFile(filename) {
    var myDocument = document.querySelector("body");
    filesystem.root.getFile(filename, {}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                // if you save the file with atob (ascii to binary), then:
                img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+btoa(this.result);
                // if you don't save the file without atob, then:
                // img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+this.result;
                myDocument.appendChild(img)
            };

            reader.readAsText(file);
        }, errorHandler);

    }, errorHandler);
}
```